# Как сделать ещё одну новую правку подряд?

Tags: поддержка

Допустим. Отредактировал вопрос --- изменил форматирование кода. Затем через минуту решил отредактировать заголовок. Я как программист, хочу чтобы эта правка была атомарной, хочу "сделать новый коммит", а не "--amend". Но, так как, прошло мало времени система заставляет меня сделать "--amend". Как обойти это, и сделать "сделать новый коммит" ?

Comment: подождать чуть больше времени

Comment: @Grundy сколько точно неизвестно?

Comment: Вроде пять минут

Comment: @Danis И это правильный ответ.

Comment: Как хак вроде работает во второй раз подкорректировать описание правки, но оно как-то так странно то работает то нет, что не могу сказать, что это вообще стоящий приём.

Comment: @AK `то работает то нет` — угу. Еще тут в основном работает, а на enSO нет.

Comment: @AK можно сделать правку, написать комментарий, и делать новую правку

Comment: и удалить комментарий ) прикольный хак, не знал: как-нибудь опробую.

Comment: @AK проверил, не работаете, наверно комментарий должен быть от другого участника